# Scala spark - flatmap or alternative function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im new to spark coming from apache flink and looking for some advice on some transformation requirement. In flink i would manage this with a stateful flatmap, but not sure if the same applies in spark, or there is a better alternative.

Im reading from one delta table and need to write the output to another

Given the below table format

| Time | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2023-11-01T12:51" | ID | 75B |
| "2023-11-01T12:52" | Pressure | 5 |
| "2023-11-01T12:56" | Resistance | 20 |
| "2023-11-01T12:57" | ID | 55C |
| "2023-11-01T12:57" | Pressure | 10 |

I require the output as

| Time | Name | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2023-11-01T12:52" | Pressure | 5 | 75B |
| "2023-11-01T12:56" | Resistance | 20 | 75B |
| "2023-11-01T12:57" | Pressure | 10 | 55C |

Essentially aligning every value with the active ID at the time, all of the data is time series.

So my questions are

1. What is the best method to follow for this alignment. A stateful flatmap or its manageable with simple data frame transformations
2. If flatmap, a good resource to follow to implement this kind of procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique identifier can be assigned to each row with `row_number` function, and previous `ID` row found by Window with range. Received dataframe joined to itself:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2023-11-01T12:51", "ID", "75B"),
  ("2023-11-01T12:52", "Pressure", "5"),
  ("2023-11-01T12:56", "Resistance", "20"),
  ("2023-11-01T12:57", "ID", "55C"),
  ("2023-11-01T12:57", "Pressure", "10")
).toDF("Time", "Name", "Value")

val withCurrentRowWindow = Window.orderBy("Time")
  .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

val withIdRowDetected = df
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("Time")))

  .withColumn("id_row_number", max(
    when($"Name" === lit("ID"), $"row_number").otherwise(null)
  ).over(withCurrentRowWindow))

withIdRowDetected.show(false)

val result = withIdRowDetected
  .alias("non_ids")
  .where($"Name" =!= lit("ID"))
  .join(withIdRowDetected
    .alias("ids")
    .where($"Name" === lit("ID")),
    $"non_ids.id_row_number" === $"ids.row_number", "inner")
  .select($"non_ids.Time", $"non_ids.Name", $"non_ids.Value", $"ids.Value".alias("ID"))
```

Output:

```
+----------------+----------+-----+----------+-------------+
|Time            |Name      |Value|row_number|id_row_number|
+----------------+----------+-----+----------+-------------+
|2023-11-01T12:51|ID        |75B  |1         |1            |
|2023-11-01T12:52|Pressure  |5    |2         |1            |
|2023-11-01T12:56|Resistance|20   |3         |1            |
|2023-11-01T12:57|ID        |55C  |4         |4            |
|2023-11-01T12:57|Pressure  |10   |5         |4            |
+----------------+----------+-----+----------+-------------+

+----------------+----------+-----+---+
|Time            |Name      |Value|ID |
+----------------+----------+-----+---+
|2023-11-01T12:52|Pressure  |5    |75B|
|2023-11-01T12:56|Resistance|20   |75B|
|2023-11-01T12:57|Pressure  |10   |55C|
+----------------+----------+-----+---+
```

Note: Window without partitions used, performance can be bad.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution using window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq((5, "Pressure", "10"), (4, "ID", "55C"), (3, "Resistance", "20"), (2, "Pressure", "5"), (1, "ID", "75B"))
val inputDf = spark.createDataFrame(d1).toDF("time", "name", "value")
inputDf.createOrReplaceTempView("t")
val sql = """
select time, name, value, MAX(time_tmp) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ID
from (
  select *, CASE name WHEN "ID" THEN time ELSE -1 END as time_tmp
  from t
) as t2
"""
val outputDf = spark.sql(sql)

inputDf.show()
outputDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+-----+
|time|      name|value|
+----+----------+-----+
|   5|  Pressure|   10|
|   4|        ID|  55C|
|   3|Resistance|   20|
|   2|  Pressure|    5|
|   1|        ID|  75B|
+----+----------+-----+

+----+----------+-----+---+
|time|      name|value| ID|
+----+----------+-----+---+
|   1|        ID|  75B|  1|
|   2|  Pressure|    5|  1|
|   3|Resistance|   20|  1|
|   4|        ID|  55C|  4|
|   5|  Pressure|   10|  4|
+----+----------+-----+---+
```